# Transfer Music file from USB into "Automatically Add to iTunes" and play it with Applescript

Tags: macos, usb, applescript, itunes

I need a script that moves a music file from my USB Music folder into the "Automatically Add to iTunes" folder, and then plays that file. This is what I have so far:

```
tell application "Finder"
move items from "LEXAR:Pictures:Music:" to "Macintosh HD:User:" --this is where i'm lost, i need the path that doesnt include my name as the User
--and i need some way to tell itunes to play that file
```

sorry about the weird code setup. What I want to happen is I insert my USB into someone's computer, click on this script as an .app, and it will transfer the files in my USB under "Music" into the "Automatically Add to iTunes" and then launching iTunes, playing that music file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set userPath to (path to home folder as text)
    set directoryPath to "Music:iTunes:iTunes Media:Automatically Add to iTunes"
    set fullPath to userPath & directoryPath
    move every file of folder "LEXAR:Pictures:Music:" to folder fullPath
end tell
```

and then use that variable in order to get to the home folder of the currently logged in user. From there, you can reference the Automatically Add to iTunes folder :)

Comment: Thanks. The only problem is that I don't know how to write it. Let's say that "Automatically Add to iTunes" is inside "itunes media" inside "itunes" inside "Music" inside "MyName" inside "Macintosh HD". How would I write it? Also, would it be easier to to just move that file into itunes "Music" in the form of the artist folder, album folder, and file?

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect how you could go about doing that - another option is you could also prompt the user for a folder (in case you change USBs?). As for playing the song in iTunes specifically I'm not too sure but perhaps you could try looking at a way to see the most recently added song, and then play that?

Comment: If I've answered your question can you please mark it as the answer? Thanks :)